# Adding refreshControl to collectionView inside a collectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, refresh

I have a UICollectionViewController (`HomeViewController`) with 3 cells.
 Each cell is as big as the screen's size.
In the last cell I have another UICollectionView (`collectionView`) to display data.
This data should be refreshed every time I pull to refresh.

But that does not work.

This is the code so far:

**HomeViewController**

```
class HomeViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


    let thirdCellId = "thirdCell"


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let thirdCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: thirdCellId, for: indexPath) as! ThirdCell

            thirdCell.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshData), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

            return thirdCell
    }


    @objc func refreshData(sender: UIRefreshControl) {

        let cell = sender.superview as! ThirdCell  <--- gives error: Could not cast value of type 'UICollectionView' to 'ExploreCell'

        cell.loadData() 
        cell.refreshControl.endRefreshing()

        print("Did work")
    }

}
```

**ThirdCell** code:

```
class ThirdCell: UICollectionViewCell, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super .init(frame: frame)

    setupCollectionView()
    loadData()
    setupRefreshControl()
}


// --- CollectionView --- 


    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        let cv = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cv.delegate = self
        cv.dataSource = self
        return cv
    }()


    func setupCollectionView() {
        self.addSubview(collectionView)
        // Setup constraints
    }


// --- RefreshControl --- 


    var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
        let rfs = UIRefreshControl()
        // Handle action in HomeViewController
        return rfs
    }()


    func setupRefreshControl() {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            collectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
        } else {
            collectionView.addSubview(refreshControl)
        }
        refreshControl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        refreshControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 30).isActive = true
        refreshControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }



    func loadData() {
        // Load data
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: If each cell takes up the entire screen, is there any reason you aren't using `UIPageViewController` instead?

Comment: Haven't thought about that, thanks. I'll try this. But is there a way to fix the problem I currently have?

Comment: I can't think of a simple way offhand, I think you're better off not using a `UICollectionView` as your parent.